# Best way to save a secretKey

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js, solana

I'm learning Solana API on ReactJS.
After generating a keypair you can recreate the same keypair with the secretKey.
How can I save this keypair? I'm using react and I want to recreate always the same keypair unless I generate another.

Comment: Might not be the safest solution but localstorage is a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of "best" is a matter of opinion, but in your case, since you're just learning and using this keypair for development, your best bet is to save it to your local disk.

If you're developing in a browser environment, you can just hardcode the bytes of your secret key in the code.

Later on, once you're deployed to mainnet and want to work safely, a hardware wallet is likely your best option.

You can find more information on wallets in the docs: https://docs.solana.com/wallet-guide

Answer (score 0):

I write it to a file. Create `generateKeypair.js` in src directory and add this

```
const fs=require('fs')
const anchor=require("@project-serum/anchor")
const account=anchor.web3.Keypair.generate()
fs.writeFileSync('./keypair.json',JSON.stringify(account))
```

then execute this script once:

```
node src/generateKeypair.js
```